# Vite + Vue3: "node:net" has been externalized

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to create a websocket in Vue3 with vite, but the returned promise is always:

> Promise { : "rejected", : Error }
> ​
> : "rejected"
> ​
> : Error: Module "node:net" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "node:net.Socket" in client code.

This is what my function looks like:

```
import net from 'node:net';

export async function checkPort(
  port: number,
  { host = 'localhost', timeout = 1000 } = {},
) {
  if (typeof host !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('Specify a `host`');
  }

  const promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const socket = new net.Socket();

    const onError = () => {
      socket.destroy();
      reject();
      console.log('error');
    };

    socket.setTimeout(timeout);
    socket.once('error', onError);
    socket.once('timeout', onError);

    socket.connect(port, host, () => {
      socket.end();
      resolve();
    });
  });

  console.log(promise);
  try {
    await promise;
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong (or a better way to do it) are very welcomed!